# $\int_{0}^{2\pi }\cos^{2}(nx)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi }\cos^{2}(nx)dx$$

Why If I solve the integral by parts I get an answer and if I solve by using formula I get another answer. What's wrong ?

By parts:

I take $f(x)=\cos^2(nx)$ so $f'(x)=-n\sin(2nx)$ and $g'(x)=1$ so $g(x)=x$

I obtain $x\cos^{2}(nx) +n\int_{0}^{2\pi }\sin(2nx)dx$

The second integral is $0$ and when I replace in the first part with $0$ and $2\pi$ I get $2\pi-0=2\pi$

On the other hand, if I use the formula $\cos^2(x)=(1+\cos2x)/2$ and integrate I get the response $\pi$ which is the right answer.

Why solving by parts doesn't work ?

Comment: The problem is in the integral you get on the other side. If the original integral is $$\int f(x) g'(x) dx,$$ the ensuing one should be $$\int f'(x) g(x) dx = -n \int x\sin(2nx) dx.$$ You're missing the $x$ from the integral.

Comment: Yes, you need to subtract $\int g(x)f'(x)\,dx,$ and you've subtracted $\int g'(x)f'(x)\,dx.$

Comment: I wonder why the downvote? Seems like a complete and decent question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$f'(x)=-2n\cos(nx)\sin nx$$

Comment: I think OP is alright there; I'm pretty sure they applied $\sin(2t) = 2\sin(t)\cos(t)$

Comment: Yeah, I made the same error.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

In the integral of a trigonometric monomial $\sin ^rx\cos^s x$, if an exponent is odd you proceed to a substitution, taking the corresponding function as the integration variable. If both  exponents are even, you first use the linearisation formulæ, to obtain smaller degrees. So here
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi }\cos^{2}(nx)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi }\frac{1+\cos 2nx}2\,\mathrm dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos(nx)$ and $\sin(nx)$ are $2\pi-$periodic and are just a phase shift of one another we have $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nx)^2\mathop{dx}=\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(nx)^2\mathop{dx}$

So for $n\neq 0$ $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nx)^2\mathop{dx}=\dfrac 12\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\cos(nx)^2+\sin(nx)^2\right) \mathop{dx}=\dfrac 12\int_0^{2\pi} 1\mathop{dx}=\pi$